Gleaning LWC source code from the browser
It's a pity blueprints of the Lightning Design System are largely ignoring Javascript. This is getting more serious now that the base components recipes have become stale. Can relevant LWC sources be extracted via the browser?
For Javascript the situation doesn't look too bad. If I want to build something resembling the original Javascript of the LWC, I replace the found constructor by class fields, find the code of separate modules inserted on top of the class, splitting it up into separate files, etc. Maybe the most tricky bit is identifying the imports, but there's usually the signature of the IIFE with an inspiring parameter list on top of the file.
But how to get the markup? E.g. if I have the following markup in my own LWC...
<template>
    <div>{helloWorld}</div>
    <c-wc-test-child></c-wc-test-child>
</template>

... I would like to get something coming close to line number 2+3 - at best something a Chrome plugin can figure out according to a given set of rules ;-) Is there a moment in the execution of the Javascript, where the markup is fully assembled, but variables are not yet substituted?
(When the renderCallback is executed, this.template.innerHTML is <div>Hello World!</div><c-wc-test-child></c-wc-test-child>, i.e. variables are already substitued.)
One approach to this appears to be the return statement of the tmpl function:
function tmpl($api, $cmp, $slotset, $ctx) {...

with its return value piecing together the future template code. Prior to sending the payload to the browser, the "original" markup got decomposed into a number of strings and variables. All this is assembled in the returned array by nested calls of api_* functions: api_slot, api_bind, api_static_fragment etc. But playing with tmpl and these functions, it becomes clear it's neither straightforward to deduce the inner structure of the markup from here. tmpl is called each time the HTML has to be re-rendered. All variables are instantly replaced.
Are there better ways to extract the source from the browser? Is this the closest we can get? (Note: I'm well aware Salesforce code can change without warning anytime.)

The "raw" .html files are never sent to the client, so you can't recover them. You are correct that the tmpl function is what hydrates the component. This is the closest you can get to the source. You could technically parse it, I suppose, but it's undocumented and not straightforward without some research.

Thank you, that's helpful. If I find the time, I will have a look at the api_* functions and see, if their way of processing the given inputs facilitates some automatic extraction of the markup.
